# Objective-c define variable inside foreach

Tags: objective-c

I have a foreach loop and inside this loop, I would like to define variable for each item like so:

```
for (NSArray *array in datasource.jobList){
        SDataGridColumn *array = [[SDataGridColumn alloc] initWithTitle:array];
        array.width = @80;
        [spreadSheet addColumn:array];
    }
```

but I get a two warnings:

```
Unused variable 'array'
```

and

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'SDataGridColumn *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'
```

Is what I am trying to possible ?

Thanks,

Comment: Two var called `array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your loop variable, defined inside the for statement

```
for (NSArray *array in datasource.jobList)
```

has the same name of your internal variable

```
SDataGridColumn *array = [[SDataGridColumn alloc] initWithTitle:array];
```

Your must change name in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (NSArray *array in [datasource jobList])
{
     SDataGridColumn *columnArray = [[SDataGridColumn alloc] initWithTitle:array];
     columnArray.width = @80;
     [spreadSheet addColumn:columnArray];
}
```